# Anyone had Digispark Attiny85 not SEEN by some USB controllers but seen via HUB or DOCK on same device?

Tags: attiny85, digispark

I have purchased a couple of different types of DigiSpark Attiny85 clones (couldn't find originals available) and they have worked great except some devices (so far, just laptops) don't see the device AT ALL.

It's not that they don't recognise it and so is a driver issue - there is nothing to apply the driver to, no indication that the thing is even plugged in other than the light comes on (so I know it has power).

More frustratingly, if I plug the Digisparks in to any problematic device via a docking station, USB hub, etc. everything works as expected (confirming the drivers are ok) and I can write scripts to the digispark.

I've tried updating the Nucleous bootloader but the problem persists.  I get this problem on three modern laptops (HP & 2 Dells) but my older Lenovo laptops have no problems.  Not sure if here is an issue with modern USB controllers?

UPDATE: Everything points towards it just being an issue with Digispark's and some USB 3.0 controllers.  The clock is correctly set at 16.5Mhz so not sure what else to do other than write these-off as a reliable device.

Anyone had any experience of this or have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be the bit-banging implementation of the USB protocol via the built-in oscillator, I don't know, it's just a thought. Modern USB controllers might be picky on timing. Perhaps you can check and adjust the frequency of this oscillator. I have one of these "fake" clones (rev.3) and it works on a new and an old ThinkPad.

Comment: @thebusybee, thanks for comment - from what I've read, there seems to be issues with timing specifically with some USB 3.0 controllers which is inline with what you've said and my observations (http://digistump.com/board/index.php?topic=1622.0).
I'm not familiar with adjusting the frequency and haven't seen anything on this subject in the various posts about this issue so I suspect it might just be an inherent issue that isn't going away.  I've tried updating micronucleous to the latest version too but no luck.

Comment: Not sure why I was down-voted but I've read the criteria and don't feel like it was warranted.  Does anyone have any suggestions so I can avoid it in the future.  Personally, I'll never down-vote with commenting why I've done so.

Comment: Well, I did not downvote, because you did some research and made your issue clear. Oh, BTW, you surely mean "_with**out** commenting why_", don't you? -- Perhaps someone with a logic analyzer and some USB decoder _and_ a similar setup can shed some light on the problem. Many years ago I needed 2 weeks to find protective diodes with too large capacitance this way. -- Or, if you happen to use Linux, you could try to track the system's messages while plugging in. Or you use Wireshark and its USB driver to check at a very low level. -- Anyway, I cannot help further right now, sorry.

Comment: @thebusybee, yep you're right - I missed the "out" out If you know what I mean!).  Really appreciate the help - I'm going to give up on these boards as they are just too hit and miss!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is down to issues around Attiny85 timing with USB 3.0 chipsets and so isn't something that can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The four USB traces on the digistump board are NOT to perfect specification and don't work with 4/5 conductor USB3 ports.  Use a dremel or band saw and cut about 2/3 of the end off the digistump Printed Circuit Board USB plug. Leave enough of the original four traces to solder to.  Cut off the plug end from an older USB cord. After carefully cutting away and cleaning off the plastic and old wires on the actual USB plug, it fits perfectly to line up to the old (now shorter) traces on the digistump. Be sure trace sides are the same direction on old and new plug and solder all four connections.  Add some superglue and/or silicone for strength and it should work every time with any USB port.

WZ